# want to pass the value of texteditorformfield to next page which consist statefull widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

/*i want to pass the value of textformfield to the next page which is given below and print on next page but on the next page showing nothing except the appbar */
Form(
key: _formfield,
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [

```
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  controller: name_Controller,               
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    
                    /***********************************************/
                     //testing code
                    var response = await signIn();
                    print(response);
                    if(response == '1') //**working fine till here...enter in if block and redirected to next page, but the value of name_Controller is passing to next page and not showing any error**
                    {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => demoScreen(name_Controller.text.toString())  //**sending the name_Controller value to next page**
                          ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                              content: Text('Invalid credential')
                          ));
                    }
                    ///////************************************************/////////////////
                    }
                  },

                  child:Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    //borderRadius: BorderRadius(5),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                        'Log In',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ),
     Future<String?> signIn() async {
        var dio = Dio();
        try {
          var response = await dio.post('https://abc.in/xyz/test.php',
              data: {
                "method"  : "login_check",
                "username" : name_controller.text,
                "pass" : _passwd
              },
              options: Options(
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                  }
              ));
          mapResponse = jsonDecode(response.data);
          var x;
          x = mapResponse['data'][0]['sucess'];
          return x;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
        return null;

  }

}



//**this is the next page which is demoScreen..i want value of name_controller to be printed here----->**
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class demoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  var test;
  demoScreen(this.test); //**constructor of demoScreen collecting the value of name_Controller from previous page**

  @override
  State<demoScreen> createState() => _demoScreenState();
}

class _demoScreenState extends State<demoScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('demo'),
      ),
      body: Text('${widget.test}'), //**try to print the value of name_Controller of previous page which is stored in test variable in this page.**
    );
  }
}
```

**output:
blank screen....nothing is showing in this screen except appbar**

Comment: You should try to debug and check if value is getting passed in to the next screen.

Comment: value is passing to api and get the response accordingly but the value is not to the next page..what should i do now

Answer (score 0):

Define a new route that takes a string parameter in its constructor, which will be used to initialize the state of your stateful widget. For example:

```
class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  const NextPage({required this.text});

  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Next Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(widget.text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In your first page, when the user submits the form, push the new route and pass the text value as a parameter:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => NextPage(text: textEditingController.text),
  ),
);
```

Comment: not working still showing blank screen